what to do when opening someone else's Xcode project?
I'm a bit confused about standard behaviour when Working with other developers.
Are my actions, described below, a normal practice?
note: I covered team id and names for privacy concerns, but I think screenshots where useful for explaining my doubts.
When I start collaboration, I download the project. First issue is about the team (I'm never ben "included" in a Team, never got some certificate, two things I know exist but I never experienced) and I get something like this, where "Fooo" is someone else's name (developer or institution).:

I get this too, and here is the issue:

I can understand that there is no team  on my Mac, and if I do not receive from others some credentials, I cannot match the Team in red (which should be the orignal developer's team, right?).
my questions:

is it right / normal that I need to select my own developer account, with my name?
is it right / normal that once I selected my profile, I need to rename the bundle identifier?

I can understand that the Bundle id is UNIQUE, but I'm wondering if this  whole behavior is a standard one, I always worked alone, so I do not have chance to verify with other than my client's team, which usually are not that happy to explain things.
thanks in advance


If you just want to test things out, you can run the project on a simulator without making any changes. However, if you’re part of the team, it’s best to ask them to add you to the account. While modifying the bundle ID and account can get the code running, you may lose access to certain deeper features that depend on the original bundle ID. (like some entitlements)

You cannot run the app without entering valid credentials. If you already have personal credentials, just use them. You will then be able to build and run to a simulator and (assuming you have a paid developer membership) to a device.
All this is true for any Xcode project you download from (say) GitHub. You always have to change the Team from them to you in order to build and run. It becomes second nature.
You do not need to be part of someone else's team in order to collaborate with them. However, depending on the nature of your relationship with their team, their team might want to onboard you into the team, possibly under a new Apple ID. But that's up to them.

so, is it standard even renaming the app bundled?

No, there shouldn't generally be any reason to do that.
